# Jquery - Automatically Closing Hidden Divs

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

I have this piece of jQuery (bottom of post) which allows for divs to be hidden then on button click to slide out. I have 3 hidden divs, however once one has been clicked the previous div stays open and I am looking for a way to automatically close the divs when another is opened. Thanks in advance!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#pop-out button').click(function() {
  var $lefty = $(this).next();
   $lefty.animate({
    left: parseInt($lefty.css('left'),10) == 0 ?
    -$lefty.outerWidth() :
    0
   });
  });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#fl-container").show();
});
```

Comment: could you provide more information such as:
- working example with HTML
- what do you call "open" for a div? do you mean visible?

Comment: you install the ready handler twice. afaik, they aren't stackable, so your click handler would be lost.

Answer (score 0):

just give all divs that can be show/hidden the same class name and do

```
 $(".ClassNameHere").hide();
    $("#fl-container").show();
```